# Are there any general heuristics for Kalman filter noise parameters

Tags: kalman-filters, unscented-kalman-filter

Are there any generally applicable heuristics for [Kalman filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter) noise parameters? I am working with a non-linear unscented filter and getting an initial guess for the noise covariances $Q_k$ and $R_k$ is proving difficult as [wikipedia cautions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Estimation_of_the_noise_covariances_Qk_and_Rk). Specifically I am wondering if the condition number of the innovation covariance $S_k$ should be below some value? Alternatively in a well running filter, should each element in the optimal Kalman gain $K_k$ be in some range? Is there some other rule of thumb that would help quickly guide me towards a "sane" filter so I can use other optimization techniques to fine tune the parameters? Thank you.

Comment: It depends on your application. Sometimes R and Q are chosen based on the model. I recommend reading https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/abstract/document/6626597?casa_token=oroiTLL1ZggAAAAA:5xW15OXvGpCazSla1h_okSAkxqDG1Qd97YpvJShmNIPHWya9Xy44HEdF0boURmmVAItZsjN1XRc

Comment: A good initial guess for $\mathbf R_k$ is the actual anticipated measurement noise.  A good initial guess for $\mathbf Q_k$ is the actual anticipated process noise, plus the "virtual" process noise inherent in the unscented transform.  Are you starting there?

Comment: @TimWescott what do you mean by "virtual" process noise? Is that diagonal or does it have cross terms? My initial guesses so far have not been good, such that the estimated state diverges, and often $S_k$ becomes singular.

Comment: When you do the prediction step, are you using a nonlinear ODE solver to move the state forward, or are you using the linearized model from the unscented transformation?  Either one of these is going to have a certain amount of error, and that error can be treated as noise.  So -- are you using that?  How _did_ you arrive at $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf Q$?

Comment: Thanks for the tips. I suspect my issue may be my choices for state variables given what is observable. Specifically the observations are nearly totally independent of mean of two of the state variables and only really measure the difference between them, which I suspect leads to the numerical issues. Perhaps I need to adjust what parameters I am tracking in state. Does that sound plausible? Thanks

Comment: If you are providing no information about a system mode (in this case the sum of those two variables), then quite naturally the uncertainty of that mode will increase.  In that case, a well-chosen $\mathbf R$ and $\mathbf Q$ would still cause the variance of that mode to increase.  This is a problem with the underlying observability of your system, not in how you're modeling it.

Comment: There's an algorithm called the prediction error decomposition which is used to estimate the $R$ and $Q$ in kalman filter models. It is discussed in Andrew Harvey's blue textbook which is  on Amazon. It's expensive to purchase for just one concept  so maybe you can find something online about it.

Answer (score 0):

I found the following advice the most useful in practice: **the relative values of** $R_k$ and $Q_k$ are the most important.
So if your model is *less reliable* than your measurements, then choose $Q_k > R_k$, if the model is *more reliable,* then $Q_k < R_k.$

The reason for this heuristic is the fact that the Kalman gain $K_k$ includes $Q_k$ in the nominator, whereas both $Q_k$ and $R_k$ in the denominator (cf. e.g. the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kalman_filter#Update)).